# Map list of elements to category of element in pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have been googling a lot, but I still can't find a quick way to do so.
Say I have a column in my csv file:

```
1. C.Ronald         
2. Conor McGregor    
3. Lionel Messi
4. LeBron James
5. Derrick Rose   
6. Tom Brady
7. ...
8. ...
```

and so on, I want to replace those name as the following three categories  through python:

```
1. Soccer player
2. MMA fighter
3. Soccer player
4. NBA player
5. NBA player
6. NFL plaer
7. ... 
8. ...
```

How can I replace 'C.Ronald','Lionel Messi' and those soccer player's name, in to a class at once, but not one by one, since I have a long column.

Comment: Little bit of code would help - especially something that allows someone to easily build a testable dataset. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has useful advice about asking questions.

Comment: How will pandas know those players align to those categories? Is there a mapping data of some kind? Does Python need to crawl the internet to find these names and their league associations?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a mapping form type of player to list of players.

You can then use a data-oriented package such as `pandas` to perform the mapping for you via a dictionary:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""C.Ronald
Conor McGregor
Lionel Messi
LeBron James
Derrick Rose
Tom Brady
""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, names=['Player'])

d = {'Soccer player': ['C.Ronald', 'Lionel Messi'],
     'MMA fighter': ['Conor McGregor'],
     'NBA player': ['LeBron James', 'Derrick Rose'],
     'NFL player': ['Tom Brady']}

df['Category'] = df['Player'].map(lambda x: next((k for k, v in d.items() if x in v), None))

#            Player       Category
# 0        C.Ronald  Soccer player
# 1  Conor McGregor    MMA fighter
# 2    Lionel Messi  Soccer player
# 3    LeBron James     NBA player
# 4    Derrick Rose     NBA player
# 5       Tom Brady     NFL player
```

**Explanation**

`next` on a generator expression returns the next iteration; it stops when it finds the first instance. This will only become an issue if you had a sportsperson in more than one category. The argument `None` only gets returned if no match is found.

Comment: What is the significance of using 'next' here ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat, `next` on a generator expression returns the next iteration; it stops when it finds the first instance. This will only become an issue if you had a sportsperson in more than one category. The argument `None` only gets returned if no match is found.